# Blender Render baking - Rasterzation and Eevee

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, eevee-render-engine

Blender Render = Baking a normal map from a High Poly to a Low Poly works fine, it doesn't care about Intersections at all, no errors.

Cycles Baking + Cage Baking = Any intersections of mesh result in artifacts (Mostly between toes, fingers and in the mouth.

Someone told me that Eevee is a Rasterization engine similar to Blender Render, will Eevee baking behave preferably similar to Blender Render?